# UDP Stop-and-Wait: identifying false messages

Tags: java, security, authentication, udp

I am currently building a fast paced multi-player game where security is a big concern.

I have implemented stop-and-wait (a temporary measure, for simplicity's sake) over UDP in Java.

However, I'm concerned that a malicious party could send false acks or messages to the sender or receiver respectively, making the sequence numbers go out of sync — essentially causing either messages to be lost (crashing the game!) or the sender to resend indefinitely.

Further up in my application, each participant is identified by an RSA public key, so I could add a signed hash to each message for authentication purposes... but this greatly increases header size and muddles my architecture layers somewhat.

Is this a common approach? Are there good known solutions to this problem?

Comment: Since UDP packets are unreliable (they are not guaranteed to appear in the order they are sent, nor is delivery guaranteed), your game must defend itself against out of sequence packets, missing packets, and duplicated packets.  It should not crash.  Actually, your game server can't afford to crash regardless of what the clients send — you may reject or ignore stuff, but you can't afford to crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Jonathan said. Generally speaking, you need to provide your own means of defending against out of order or dropped packets while using UDP. There isn't a "standard" way of dealing with this problem -- other than using TCP instead. You can, as you said, validate the client's identity on every packet -- but keep in mind validating the client's identity, even with something like RSA -- doesn't help you against malicious clients. They can just connect to the game server, validate themselves, and start sending garbage. After all, they are who they say they are.

For most game server designs, to my (albeit limited) understanding, usually the server has the notion of a "tick" -- whereby clients can register that some events happen within the tick, and the server enforces the rules against what the clients send. But when the tick ends, any events received by the server corresponding to that tick are discarded. This adds a race element which does not increase actual security of the system, but does add an element which makes it more difficult.

Of course making any system like this "secure" in that a client couldn't spoof their origin would essentially require doing a TLS tunnel, which I would assume won't meet your performance requirements.

Comment: I should probably expand more on what I'm doing. The game is peer-to-peer (aside for lobby set-up) and each player must present their RSA identity on connection to the lobby (another player acting as host). Each player has a full copy of the game state and players must send all of the commands they issue to all other players. My concern is that a malicious player could force others to drop from the game by sending false messages with the right sequence number.

Comment: @user1256041: Yes, you have yourself a design bug. There isn't a way to secure that kind of a design. You've got a rock solid proof of the client's identity (RSA), but nothing says an authenticated client can't be evil too.

Comment: It's a tricky situation. There are simply too many units to send them all between players, so each player has the whole state and commands are sent instead. Sudden thought: a player can prove that another is being malicious if all packets are signed. This means the honest players can boot a malicious player on another player presenting them the malicious packets.

Comment: @user: No, signing only proves that the sender did in fact send the given message (and not some man in the middle). It doesn't prove that the sender him/herself were not being malicious.

Comment: Well that depends on the message. If a player sends out a message that they should not have sent, then the receiving player can use that as evidence for the sending player being malicious to the other players.

Comment: @user: That assumes that you have some means of telling the message of being malicious. What if I send a message that says that another player is malicious, maliciously? Instant denial of service

Comment: Well it won't be signed by the player, so it will be rejected as poor evidence.

Comment: @user: Erm, why can't it be signed by the player? As I said; signing doesn't offer any protection here -- a client can just sign their malicious "turn off player XXXX" packets and you're back in the same hole.

Comment: If all messages are signed then we have proof of origin. If a player sends a dodgy message, then the recipient can show it to the other players the message and a decision can be made to kick that player.

Comment: @User: That has a couple of problems -- what if you can't fit the bad message along with one's own signature into a UDP packet? How would the other players respond to the request to kick? (That kind of message would need to be "protected" too) How do you stop the data explosion of one potentially malicious client sending large bad packets to every one of the machines in the network, thus leading to  n^2 data on the part of the network but only n on the part of the malicious client? What if many malicious "clients" connect to the network at the same time? etc.